# GET parameter value contains comma, netty encodes it - breaking the service

Tags: rest, http, netty

I'm consuming a Weather.com web service which takes a "latitude,longitude" value (e.g. "40.87601089477539,-87.43512725830078") and using Netty to handle the network communication.

The service responds with an error, which is caused by my parameter value's comma being escaped (i.e. "40.87601089477539%2C-87.43512725830078").

```
# works (when a confidential API key is added)
http://api.weather.com/v2//location?geocode=40.87601089477539,-87.43512725830078

# doesn't work
http://api.weather.com/v2//location?geocode=40.87601089477539%2C-87.43512725830078
```

The escaping is done in in `com.ning.http.client.RequestBuilderBase.toUrl(boolean encode)`. If I was able to pass false to it then my problem would be solved but it is the Netty library that makes a callout to this method rather than me, and the option is hard-coded.

1) Is there a workaround for Netty consumers? 2) What's the right way to fix this?

**EDIT** Additional details

Stack trace:

```
RequestBuilderBase$RequestImpl.toUrl(boolean) line: 166 
RequestBuilderBase$RequestImpl.getUrl() line: 118   
RequestBuilderBase$RequestImpl.<init>(Request) line: 78 
RequestBuilder(RequestBuilderBase<T>).<init>(Class<T>, Request) line: 323   
RequestBuilder.<init>(Request) line: 42 
NettyAsyncHttpProvider$HttpProtocol.handle(ChannelHandlerContext, MessageEvent) line: 2115  
NettyAsyncHttpProvider.messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext, MessageEvent) line: 1128  
NettyAsyncHttpProvider(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler).handleUpstream(ChannelHandlerContext, ChannelEvent) line: 75   
DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext, ChannelEvent) line: 564    
DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(ChannelEvent) line: 792    
ChunkedWriteHandler.handleUpstream(ChannelHandlerContext, ChannelEvent) line: 141   
DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext, ChannelEvent) line: 564    
DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(ChannelEvent) line: 792    
HttpContentDecompressor(HttpContentDecoder).messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext, MessageEvent) line: 100  
HttpContentDecompressor(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler).handleUpstream(ChannelHandlerContext, ChannelEvent) line: 75  
DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext, ChannelEvent) line: 564    
DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(ChannelEvent) line: 792    
Channels.fireMessageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext, Object, SocketAddress) line: 296    
HttpClientCodec$Decoder(ReplayingDecoder<T>).unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext, Object, SocketAddress) line: 600   
HttpClientCodec$Decoder(ReplayingDecoder<T>).callDecode(ChannelHandlerContext, Channel, ChannelBuffer, ChannelBuffer, SocketAddress) line: 584  
HttpClientCodec$Decoder(ReplayingDecoder<T>).messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext, MessageEvent) line: 445 
HttpClientCodec$Decoder(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler).handleUpstream(ChannelHandlerContext, ChannelEvent) line: 75  
HttpClientCodec.handleUpstream(ChannelHandlerContext, ChannelEvent) line: 92    
DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext, ChannelEvent) line: 564    
DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(ChannelEvent) line: 559 
Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channel, Object, SocketAddress) line: 268  
Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channel, Object) line: 255 
NioWorker.read(SelectionKey) line: 94   
NioWorker(AbstractNioWorker).processSelectedKeys(Set<SelectionKey>) line: 372   
NioWorker(AbstractNioWorker).run() line: 246    
NioWorker.run() line: 38    
ThreadRenamingRunnable.run() line: 102  
DeadLockProofWorker$1.run() line: 42    
ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1142  
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 617 [local variables unavailable] 
Thread.run() line: 745 [local variables unavailable]
```

Comment: I do not think Netty library itself depends on com.ning.http.client. But Ning is using Netty as one of its http layer.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll take a closer look at my stack trace. ning appears deeper in the stack trace than netty but perhaps that is callback-related. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I am not netty expert, but I was just thinking why not making a little function/method to convert % to , and get it to works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, none of the public libraries are to blame here. There is a flag you can set to prevent the encoding (`setUseRawUrl(true)`):

```
AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient(
    new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
        .setUseRawUrl(true)
        .build());
Future<Response> f = asyncHttpClient.prepareGet(url).execute();
Response r = f.get();
```